# How to stop the playing music when using AePlayWave

Tags: java

I have tried to write a java program which plays an audio file (*.wav) by using [AePlayWave](http://www.anyexample.com/programming/java/java_play_wav_sound_file.xml). This code worked well but I don't know how to stop the playing music (except terminating the process with Ctrl-Z). The method "stop()" or "close()" looks like not working or does not exist.
Please tell me how can I stop the playing music? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Since you example is extending a thread. Why not just pause/stop the thread.

---

```
if (this.isInterrupted()) {
  this.wait();
}
```

`this` being your class which extends Thread.

---

Just make sure you understand the `Thread` object before managing its life cycle.

For help with threads, go [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hornetq/2.2.5.Final/user-manual/en/html/thread-pooling.html)!

Comment: Thank you Josef for replying. I added the following code to [AePlayWave.java](http://www.anyexample.com/programming/java/java_play_wav_sound_file.xml) in  "public void run()", `if (this.isInterrupted()) { try {
this.wait();} catch (InterruptedException e) {e.printStackTrace();}}`. And here is my program AePlayWave ae = new AePlayWave("Doraemon.wav");
 Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
 System.out.print("Start or Stop: ");
 String str1 = keyboard.nextLine();
 switch (str1) {
  case "start":ae.start();
  break;
  case "stop": ae.interrupt();
  break;
  }

But it's still not work :(

Comment: I m sorry, I read the Help but still can not use the Syntax highlighting for codepost in comment as you did @Josef E.

Comment: You have to call an event to interrupt the thread, look how up how to pause and stop threads for examples @doraemon29